# Using Python PyInquirer and asyncio to create a user interface to trigger asynchronous actions

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, user-input

I would like to use PyInquirer and asyncio to create a user interface that can be used to trigger asynchronous actions.

A prompt should appear (using PyInquirer) that the user can select an action from. This will then create a pending task and the prompt will appear again. When the pending task has completed, the result will be printed to the standard output, even if the prompt is still on screen.

If I only want this to run once, this isn't a problem, and can be done like this:

```
import asyncio
from PyInquirer import prompt

options = {
'type': 'list',
'name': 'functionToCall',
'message': 'Choose Command',
'choices': [
    'Say Hello',
    'Exit'
]
}

async def sayHello():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("hello")

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)   

async def main():
    answers = prompt(options)
    kill = False;
    if answers['functionToCall'] == 'Say Hello':
        loop.create_task(sayHello())
    else:
        kill = True
        loop.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

If 'Say Hello' is selected, it will print to the output after 2 secconds.

But If I want the prompt to appear straight away after the previous action has been selected,this blocks the result from ever appearing. I.e

```
async def main():
    answers = prompt(options)
    kill = False;
    if answers['functionToCall'] == 'Say Hello':
        loop.create_task(sayHello())
    else:
        kill = True
        loop.stop()

    if not kill:
        loop.create_task(main())
```

The prompt will appear instantly after the last action has been selected (as desired), but "Hello" never gets printed to the output. I think this is because the `prompt()` function from PyInquire is blocking the other task from executing.

How can I get the `sayHello()` task to carry on in the background, while the program is inside the blocking `prompt()` function, and then get the `sayHello()` command to print it's result even if still inside the `prompt()` function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer:

The `prompt` function can be told to `patch_stdout = True` and `return_asyncio_coroutine = True`

This will make it return a dict of future strings, instead of a dict of strings.
The future strings can then be handled as an asyncronous task.

```
import asyncio
from PyInquirer import prompt

options = {
'type': 'list',
'name': 'functionToCall',
'message': 'Choose Command',
'choices': [
    'Say Hello',
    'Exit'
]
}

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)   


async def sayHello():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("hello!")

def handleChoice(future):
    choice = future.result()
    if choice == "Say Hello":
        loop.create_task(sayHello())
        loop.create_task(myprompt())
    else:
        loop.stop()

async def myprompt():
    future_answers_generator = prompt(options, patch_stdout = True, return_asyncio_coroutine = True)['functionToCall']    
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(future_answers_generator)
    future.add_done_callback(handleChoice)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop.create_task(myprompt())
    loop.run_forever()
```